# Angular1: TypeError: promise.catch is not a function

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using angular-ui-router, getting the below error when clicking on the links view1 and view2 in index.html. The same exmaple worked with the normal angular router, is there anything i am missing in the code ? Thanks.

```
TypeError: promise.catch is not a function
    at silenceUncaughtInPromise (angular-ui-router.js:1079)
    at silentRejection (angular-ui-router.js:1082)
    at angular-ui-router.js:1771
    at handleError (angular-ui-router.js:1614)
    at TransitionHook.invokeHook (angular-ui-router.js:1631)
    at Function.TransitionHook.invokeHooks (angular-ui-router.js:1729)
    at Transition.run (angular-ui-router.js:3475)
    at StateService.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:7015)
    at StateService.go (angular-ui-router.js:6911)
    at angular-ui-router.js:8862
```

**app.js -**

```
angular.module('app1',[
'ui.router',
'app.controller']).
config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('view1',{
            url: '/view1',
            controller: 'Controller1',
            templateUrl: '/partials/view1.html'
        }).state('view2',{
            url: '/view2/:firstname/:lastname',
            controller: 'Controller2',
            templateUrl: '/partials/view2.html',
            resolve: {
                names: function(){
                    return ['JavaScript','JQuery','Angular','Bootstrap'];
                }
            }
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

**controller.js -**

```
angular.module('app.controller',[]).
    controller('Controller1',function($scope,$location,$state){
        $scope.loadView2 = function(){      
                $state.go('view2', {
                        firstname: $scope.firstname,
                        lastname: $scope.lastname
                });
            //$location.path('/view2/'+$scope.firstname+'/'+$scope.lastname);
        }
    }).controller('Controller2',function($scope,$stateParams,names){
        $scope.firstname = $stateParams.firstname;
        $scope.lastname = $stateParams.lastname;
        $scope.names = names;
    });
```

**index.html -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/angular-route-1.2.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <title>
        Angular App
    </title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app1">
    <div>
    <ul class="menu">
<li><a ui-sref="view1">view1</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="view2">view2</a></li>
</ul>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo error near `retrun ['JavaScript','JQuery','Angular','Bootstrap'];` -> `return ['JavaScript','JQuery','Angular','Bootstrap'];`

Comment: @lin thank you, corrected that, but still getting the same error.

Comment: please create a plnkr/fiddle to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change 1**
You are using Angular UI-Router.

In your `index.html`, replace `<ng-view></ng-view>` with `<div ui-view></div>`

`ng-view` would have been valid if you had been using `ngRoute`. But, since in your project, you are using `ui.router` you should use `<div ui-view></div>`

**Change 2**
Since you are using `html5Mode`, you need to set the `base href` in `index.html`.
Add `<base href="/">` tag within the `<head>` of your `index.html`

Comment: Thanks you, by adding <div ui-view> code is working now, but still getting the same error on the console while switching between view1 and view2, any idea on this ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to indicate another change that needs to be made(base href). Other than that, the code worked fine when I copied it over to my machine.